# about errors while starting or stopping tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, tomcat7, displaytag

I am getting these warning and errors while I restart my tomcat or I stop my tomcat server. it is not interfering in my project but I guess this is serious problem while no. of user increase.

**P.S.** I have used hibernate for database connection, display tag library for display tables and have used jsp/servlet.

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkIdleResources(BasicResourcePool.java:1481)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$2000(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$CheckIdleResourcesTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1964)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/resourcepool/BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkIdleResources(BasicResourcePool.java:1481)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$2000(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$CheckIdleResourcesTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1964)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 5 more
May 27, 2014 5:20:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/ZestYouth] has started
May 27, 2014 5:20:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
May 27, 2014 5:20:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
May 27, 2014 5:20:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
May 27, 2014 5:20:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
May 27, 2014 5:20:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
May 27, 2014 5:20:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
May 27, 2014 5:20:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
May 27, 2014 5:20:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
May 27, 2014 5:20:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
May 27, 2014 5:20:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
May 27, 2014 5:20:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/ZestYouth] is completed
```

Comment: looks like the c3p0-x.y.z.jar is missing in your tomcat/project

Comment: thanks jens but this jar is for what ?
and i have included c3p0-0.9.1.jar already

Comment: This is a framework for connection pooling [see here](http://c3p0.sourceforge.net)

Comment: i have already included c3p0-0.9.1.jar..

Comment: And it is in the classpath from tomcat?

Comment: thanks jens i found solution ..problem was "conflict of jar files"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check if your webapp's JARs doesn't conflict with the server's ones...

This sometime happens when dealing with datasources and NoClassDefFOund can sometime mean "not unique class defintion found"

Comment: thanks i found solution..i inserted two jar files with lower version and higher version..means i inserted slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar and slf4j-api-1.4.1.jar files  and as well i inserted displaytag 1.2 and 1.1.